# Alert radio button text if checked

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple radio buttons of this kind:

```
<li class="row time-slot text-align">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="timeslot">TEXT
    </label>\
</li>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$('input[name="timeslot"]').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        alert($(this).text());
});
```

But nothing alerts when checking one of the radio buttons in the list. I've tried with `.click()` before `.on('change')` (to no avail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : You are reading text of radio button which is not there but to the next of it and inside label tag. So, read parent text. Also, you need not to check `:checked` as changed radio button will be checked always

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[name="timeslot"]').on('change', function(){
    //if ($(this).is(':checked')) -- not required this check
        alert($(this).parent().text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="row time-slot text-align">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="timeslot">TEXT1
    </label>\
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="timeslot">TEXT2
    </label>\
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="timeslot">TEXT3
    </label>\
  
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="timeslot">TEXT4
    </label>\
</li>
```

Comment: Definitely the most elegant answer. Also, thank you for explaining it. I couldn't see before that the text is actually the label's text and not the input's.

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) property of `nextSibling`

```js
$('input[name="timeslot"]').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked)
    alert(this.nextSibling.nodeValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="row time-slot text-align">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="timeslot">TEXT
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="row time-slot text-align">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="timeslot">TEXT 2
    </label>
  </li>
  <ul>
```

Comment: This works, but using .parent().text() is more elegant. Thank you anyway!